# This piece of C/Obj-C code puzzles me

Tags: objective-c, c

I've this simple method to shift element in an array.

```
void queuePut(uint32_t val, uint32_t *q, int qlen) {
    for (int i=qlen; i>0; i--) {
        q[i] = q[i-1];
    }
    q[0] = val;
}
```

In my class header i defined a struct

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    struct {
        uint32_t cookie[10];
        uint32_t value[10];
    } queue;
}
```

I repeatedly put elements in front of both queues

```
queuePut((uint32_t)cookie, myClassInstance->queue.cookie, cookieQueueLen);
queuePut((uint32_t)intValue, myClassInstance->queue.value, valueQueueLen);
```

When i do this my value queue layout is as follows over time:

```
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
```

When i remove the first line `queuePut((uint32_t)cookie, ...` the value queue shows this (what i want it to be):

```
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.1.1.0.0.0.0.
0.0.0.0.0.1.1.0.0.0.
```

What causes this?

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what are `cookieQueueLen` and `valueQueueLen`?

This is suspect:

```
void queuePut(uint32_t val, uint32_t *q, int qlen) {
    for (int i=qlen; i>0; i--) {
       q[i] = q[i-1];
    }
   q[0] = val;
}
```

If you're passing 10 for `qlen`, then on the first iteration you're writing to `q[10]`, which is past the bounds of the `cookie` (or `value`) arrays.  You're clobbering memory.

So in this case, you're writing past the end of the `cookie` array and into the start of the `value` array.

Comment: oh my god i can't believe how stupid i am. i was sitting hours and i din't see it! but sometimes you just need another person to point you to the obvious ;)